# roslaunch gscam

Tags: gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there any solution to launch gscam from launch file ?
gscam needs to be started directly from bin dir, else it throws errors.
I've found no working solution to changedir from roslauch.
Any idea ?
Thanks and cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11895/roslaunch-gscam/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-12-13**:
WARNING: [/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/web_apps/sample_app/webimage.launch] unknown  attribute 'device'
WARNING: [/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/web_apps/sample_app/webimage.launch] unknown  attribute 'video'

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-12-13**:

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-12-13**:
Could you guys post your launch files showing how you set the environment variable. I am also having trouble figuring out how to launch gscam from a launch file .. Here is my launch file with the errors im getting..

**Comment by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on 2011-11-28**:
Yep, I ended up using the  tags as well.

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2011-11-28**:
There's a way to set environment variables in your launch file. This is how i've always set the GSCAM_CONFIG environment variable.

**Comment by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on 2011-11-28**:
I bet it's because roslaunch doesn't use your environment variables, I'm having similar problems with PYTHONPATH.  Did you find a solution?

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2011-11-14**:
As have I, perhaps your GSCAM_CONFIG environment variable is not set to an absolute path?

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-13**:
Give us some details. What sort of errors? I'm pretty sure I've launched gscam automatically in the past...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use this line of code in your launch file. Set this right after  at the beginning of your launch file .

Or instead of setting environment variables in the launch file, edit your bash file. So first in terminal  " gedit ~/.bashrc" then add this line somewhere near the bottom of the file "GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace" . My web camera was set to video0. Now you should launch gscam without any problems.

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nandhini](https://answers.ros.org/users/1736/nandhini/) on 2012-03-26**:
how to view raw image from this? once i launched rosrun gscam gscam i'm getting success, processing...... what to do next?

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2012-03-27**:
You could use image view http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_view/cturtle in order to view the image but if you are looking for something more you might write up a new question regarding your intentions.